# need to merge data from two xml files based on record id

Tags: xslt-3.0

i have the following two xml files.
File A:

```
<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

and file B:

```
<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <id>1</id>
        <description>here we have already a description element</description>
        <otherData>s3650</otherData>
    </food>
    <food>
        <id>2</id>
        <otherData>s3250</otherData>
        <otherData2>g508</otherData2>
        <otherData3>sidi6098</otherData3>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

what i cannot achieve, is for each record that matches based on the record id, take all info from the xml file named A, and put all this info in the description element of file B, but also keep the element it came from. If the matching record does not have a description element, we add one. If it already has one, then we must be aware of where the info taken from file A starts, with a textual separator, ie "-followingInfoTakenFromFileA-". So with the above in mind, the desired output should be like:

```
 <breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <id>1</id>
        <description>here we have already a description element-followingInfoTakenFromFileA-name:Belgian Waffles-price:$5.95-calories:650</description>
        <otherData>s3650</otherData>
    </food>
    <food>
        <id>2</id>
        <otherData>s3250</otherData>
        <otherData2>g508</otherData2>
        <otherData3>sidi6098</otherData3>
        <description>name:Strawberry Belgian Waffles-price:$7.95-calories:900</description>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

Comment: Well, as you have tagged the question as [tag:xslt-3.0] and used the term "merge" in your question, have you looked into XSLT 3 features like merging https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#merging? Looks like you should be able to come up with some approach for your samples to at least show us exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: yes, i have tried with xsl:merge, and i have an output where i have many description elements. I need only one, with the separators as described in the output shown above i use saxon java 9.9 HE. my effort is similar to the example shown here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#merging

Comment: Please edit your question and show us your XSLT code together with the result it gives.

Comment: the code i have right now is not working, thus i cannot get any results at all, kind of messed everything up :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, given the sorted `id` merge keys, a simple task for `xsl:merge`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="doc-A">
<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:merge>
            <xsl:merge-source for-each-item="." select="food">
                <xsl:merge-key select="id"/>
            </xsl:merge-source>
            <xsl:merge-source for-each-item="$doc-A" select="//food">
                <xsl:merge-key select="id"/>
            </xsl:merge-source>
            <xsl:merge-action>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
                        <xsl:with-param name="merge-data" 
                          select="let $data := string-join(current-merge-group()[2]/(* except id)!(name() || ':' || .), '-')
                                  return if (description)
                                         then '-followingInfoTakenFrom' || document-uri(root(current-merge-group()[2])) || $data
                                         else $data"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:merge-action>
        </xsl:merge>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="food/description">
      <xsl:param name="merge-data"/>
      <xsl:copy>{.}{$merge-data}</xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="food[not(description)]/*[last()]">
      <xsl:param name="merge-data"/>
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <description>{$merge-data}</description>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifqo

That examples inlines the first document as a parameter for self-containedness of the sample but in the real world you could load from a URL with e.g. `<xsl:param name="doc-A" select="doc('fileA.xml')"/>`.

Comment: just for the completeness of the answer, how the above should be altered if one had a non sorted id merge keys? here is a newer example: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifqq Or this should be a new question instead?

Comment: @raka, please ask a new question with the necessary details of XML input, output you want, code you have, output or errors you get, unless using `sort-before-merge="yes"` on the `xsl:merge-source`s you have solves the problem.

Comment: this seems to do the job. If i see something strange in the output i will let you know, thank you